# Node.js connect.bodyParser throws 400 on GET request

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have written a node.js proxy server ( its [here](http://bit.ly/R50nrE) on github )

The problem is that the connect.bodyParser doesn't work very well. 
For this probject I've written my own bodyParser (see the file 'server'), but now I was testing again with connect.bodyParser. In short, I have now something like:

```
app.use(connect.bodyParser()) 
    .use(connect.query())
    .use(serveFromDB)
    .use(actAsProxyServer)
    .use(cacheContent)
    .use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err)) ;
        console.log("URL=" + req.url) ;
        console.dir(req.headers) ;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
}) ;
```

Here is output from the error function:

```
ERROR: {"status":400}
URL=/Client/rest/cache/Clients/user123/X7X1

{ host: 'localhost:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  accept: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8000/Client/index.jsp?cache=true',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'accept-charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
  cookie: 'JSESSIONID=d1cbd411e30bcfb759e29585ee23' }
```

The only thing this GET request does is calling that url (without any parameters)

Any suggestions why the **bodyParser** throws an error on this GET request ?

Cheers

UPDATE: I found the code of bodyParser [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html). In json.js it finaly throws the error because its trying to turn an empty string (because there is no body) into json. I though bodyParser is only for POST request!!

UPDATE1: found the problem: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/267 I think I have a content-type in my GET request

Comment: I usually use the body parser from the express framework. But thats because I use it for my applications all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [B2MSolutions / gzip-bodyparser](https://github.com/B2MSolutions/gzip-bodyparser)